# Two azure websites (webapps) on same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have a webapp running as an Azure website on http://www.example.com
I have controllers for www.example.com/signup and www.example.com/signin - all other stuff is put on subdomains, like username.example.com.

My question: is it possible to have another (azure) website running on http://www.example.com? E.g. with all the marketing pages etc.

Ideally I would like to give access to that second website to an external webdeveloper so that I don't have to worry that the webdeveloper have access to my main app.

Additional question: would that second website have to be asp.net? Could it be PHP? (e.g. a Wordpress site)

Comment: Do you want another site like www.marketingexample.com and www.example.com (your main site). or do you somehow want the same address to resolve to two different sites? how would the choice be made as to which site to show? you can do the former (two different domains) by using some IIS config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop child projects within Azure Websites check here : 
 **A single web project hosting both the web pages and API
One web project for the web pages, and another for the API, deployed to different websites on different servers
One web project for the web pages, and another for the API that is deployed to the same servers as an IIS application (/Services).** 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx, not sure if it can use another platform.

Comment: Thanks @Sri Kanth - I finally made it work with child projects. There was one gotcha: web.config of the child project inherit from the parent (including dependencies) so I have to prevent the inheritance.